# Encapsulating scrolling a list

Tags: java, selenium, lambda

I am coding in Java using Selenium. And there is a set of code I find myself copying from one UI action to another - the scrolling of a table. I feel I need to encapsulate it in an onject, but I am not sure how.

(Note: I am not using the Page Object Model, because I don't tend to have many test cases with the same UI elements; the UI pages are complicated and designing the page objects would take a huge time. Anyway, I do not see how using the POM, in itself, would help in this case - the code copying would just be in the page objects not test cases).

So - there can be a Dojo list which might or might not be scrollable. I need to read all elements of the list. Here's some code from one of these cases. (`groupNav` is a WebElement that is found previously; it canbeanotherelementin other cases).

```
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    WebElement gridxVScroller = null;
    boolean finishedScrolling = true;
    String prevTop = "-1";
    try {
        gridxVScroller = groupNav.findElement(By.className("gridxVScroller"));
        // if we are here and no exception has happened, there is a
        // scroller element
        if (!gridxVScroller.isDisplayed()) {
            // if the scroller is not visible, we do not use it
            gridxVScroller = null;
        } else {
            // ensure scrolling starts from the top
            jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = 0;", gridxVScroller);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException nse) {
        // there is no scroller, this is normal, do nothing
    }


    // the following loop is the scrolling loop if there is a scroller
    // if there is no scroller, the loop is executed exactly once
    do {
        //... PROCESSING OF LIST ELEMENTS THAT ARE CURRENTLY AVAILABLE GOES HERE

        // if there is a scroller, send a PgDn, wait, then check if the
        // scrolling is finished
        if (gridxVScroller != null) {
            gridxVScroller.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
            Utilities.wait(1); // the scroll needs a second to render,
                                // otherwise
                                // even scrollTop does not change
            String currentTop = String
                    .valueOf(jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].scrollTop;", gridxVScroller));
            finishedScrolling = (currentTop.equals(prevTop));
            prevTop = currentTop;
        }
    } while (!finishedScrolling);
```

So, I am somewhat tired of copying the code around, changing just the processing part. But how do I encapsulate it in a helper object in Java?

I have two ideas for now.

(1) in the constructor, determine if there is a scroller. And then have a method that pressed PgDn and determines if the scrolling has ended. The caller code would look like this:

```
ScrollHelper scrollHelper = new ScrollHelper(groupNav);
do {
    // PROCESSING GOES HERE
while (scrollHelper.continueScrolling());
```

(2) pass a function argument, supplying the processing logic in a function. I could actually find all list elements inside the object and call the processing function for each of them. This is what I would do in Python, but in Java, while the functionality exists in Java 8, I'm just not sure how to handle it.

In Python, I would pass a lambda or a local function. The code would still have access to all the local variables in the functions. In Java, local functions don't exist and lambdas seem to mean something else. So I'd have to create a separate method and use private fields to communicate with it?

Anyway - which approach should I take? Or is there a third one I did not notice?

Comment: I might be missing something, but why do we need scrolling in the first place. If all the elements are loaded in the DOM and shown in the table with a scrollbar, Selenium would be able to locate all the elemen even without scrolling. If the elements are dynamically loaded after each scroll only, the scroll bar logic is required. Is this the case ?

Comment: @Sighil yes, in the UI I am testing the elements are dynamically loaded after each scroll.